# Oracle db client silent installation failing when running through Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, silent-installer, oracleclient

### I need to install oracle 12.1 client software through chef. The chef recipe fails after the silent installation. The error details:

```
[2016-06-21T11:53:02+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2016-06-21T11:53:02+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2016-06-21T11:53:02+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /u01/media/chef- stacktrace.out
[2016-06-21T11:53:02+00:00] ERROR: execute[Install database client]  (rgbu_dbclient::dbclientinstall_12c line 81) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '6'
---- Begin output of /u01/media/dbclient/client/runInstaller -logLevel fine -waitforcompletion -ignoreSysPrereqs -silent -responseFile /u01/media/dbclient_install.rsp ----
STDOUT: Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 415 MB.   Actual 22942 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 7492 MB    Passed
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2016-06-21_11-51-31AM. Please wait ...[WARNING] [INS-13014] Target environment does not meet some optional requirements.
CAUSE: Some of the optional prerequisites are not met. See logs for details. /u01/product/oraInventory/logs/installActions2016-06-21_11-51-31AM.log
ACTION: Identify the list of failed prerequisite checks from the log: /u01/product/oraInventory/logs/installActions2016-06-21_11-51-31AM.log. Then either from the log file or from installation manual find the appropriate configuration to meet the prerequisites and fix it manually.
You can find the log of this install session at:
/u01/product/oraInventory/logs/installActions2016-06-21_11-51-31AM.log
The installation of Oracle Client 12c was successful.
Please check '/u01/product/oraInventory /logs/silentInstall2016-06-21_11-51-31AM.log' for more details.
Successfully Setup Software.
STDERR:
---- End output of /u01/media/dbclient/client/runInstaller -logLevel fine -waitforcompletion -ignoreSysPrereqs -silent -responseFile /u01/media/dbclient_install.rsp ----
Ran /u01/media/dbclient/client/runInstaller -logLevel fine        -waitforcompletion -ignoreSysPrereqs -silent -responseFile /u01/media/dbclient_install.rsp returned 6
[2016-06-21T11:53:02+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

---

The chef cookbook is run using chef-solo command.
Using the same command, silent installation is successful from bash.

Looking for a suggestion/solution.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, check the log and see what failed:

> CAUSE: Some of the optional prerequisites are not met. See logs for
>   details.
>   /u01/product/oraInventory/logs/installActions2016-06-21_11-51-31AM.log
>
> ACTION: Identify the list of failed prerequisite checks from the log:
>   /u01/product/oraInventory/logs/installActions2016-06-21_11-51-31AM.log.

Comment: Thank you for checking this. This was an ignorable/optional pre-requisite that failed. While running the silent installation through bash, it doesn't fail for this. Is there a way I can ignore this particular pre-requisite while running through chef-solo also.

Comment: The prerequite error is mentioned below:                                                  INFO: Expected Value:14.5742GB (1.5282164E7KB)
INFO: Actual Value:7.3984GB (7757820.0KB)
INFO: Error Message:PRVF-7573 : Sufficient swap size is not available on node "host" [Required = 14.5742GB (1.5282164E7KB) ; Found = 7.3984GB (7757820.0KB)]
INFO: Cause: The swap size found does not meet the minimum requirement.
INFO: Action: Increase swap size to at least meet the minimum swap space requirement.